# Search and Replace XML attribute using file name as the attribute value (Powershell or Batch File)

Tags: xml, loops, powershell, batch-file, replace

I need help to find and replace an attribute "parentid" that has "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" in each XML file in a folder. The actual filename of each file without the extension should replace the "parentid" attribute in XML. (Powershell or Batch file)

For example: C:\Folder\

4de6d1b4-b014-4cb3-bb61-649737a8217b.xml 
4d2345b4-b415-5656-12dv-832jnm89234n.xml 
...

Content of the XML:

```
   <comment id="4de6d1b4-b014-4cb3-bb61-649737a8217b" parentid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" approved="True">
      <date>2014-12-20 22:23:40</date>
      <author>Joe Doe</author>
      <email>test@example.com</email>
      <country />
      <ip>0.0.0.0</ip>
      <avatar />
      <content>Test</content>
    </comment>
```

I appreciate everyone's help!

This is what I have so far however it replaces the whole line not the actual value of the attribute.

```
@echo off &setlocal
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "search=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
set "replace=%%~nP"
set "textfile=%%~nxP"
set "newfile=%%~nP"
for /r %%P in (*) do (
(for /f "delims=" %%i in (%textfile%) do (
    set "line=%%i"
    set "line=!line:%search%=%replace%!"
    echo(!line!))>"%newfile%"
)
)
endlocal


@ECHO ON
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that you are referring to a `for` variable, namely `%%P`, outside of the loop scope, which I do not recommend.

With pure batch scripting, I would change your code to this:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "SEARCH=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"
for %%P in ("*.xml") do (
    for /F "delims=" %%I in ('
        findstr /N /R "^" "%%~P" ^& ^> "%%~fP" break
    ') do (
        set "LINE=%%I"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"
        if defined LINE set "LINE=!LINE:%SEARCH%=%%~nP!"
        >> "%%~fP" echo(!LINE!
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

This is capable of modifying the enumerated `*.xml` files in the current directory directly, so no interim file is required to do the replacement of the attribute `parentid`.

Each file is read by `findstr` which precedes every line with a line number and a colon temporarily in order not to lose empty lines (remember that `for /F` ignores such). The command line `set "LINE=!LINE:*:=!"` removes the prefix afterwards. Note that delayed expansion is toggled in the `for /F` in order not to lose any exclamation marks occurring within the files. These measures ensure that the original `*.xml` file contents are not altered, except the replaced portion of course.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of examples of loading/parsing an XML file in PowerShell, but the fastest solution in such a simple case as this one would be to use a plain text search/replace on a string that holds the entire file:

```
$searchFor = 'parentid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"'
Get-ChildItem -Literal 'c:\folder' -Filter '*.xml' -Recurse |
    Where {
        Select-String $searchFor -Path $_ -CaseSensitive -SimpleMatch
    } |
    ForEach {
        $text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)
        $text.replace($searchFor, 'parentid="' + $_.BaseName + '"') |
            Out-File (Join-Path $_.Directory "$($_.BaseName)-new.xml") -Encoding utf8
    }
```

Comment: It seems that the -Raw mode isn't working for me because I have PS v2. I get:

    Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches -Raw

Comment: How would I do it if I'm v2. Sorry I am a bit new to this.

Comment: Instead of `(Get-Content -Raw $_.FullName)` use `[IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)`. The thing is I switched to PS4.0 several years ago, so it's hard for me to keep thinking about PS2 existence. I'll update the answer though.

Comment: It seems though it is not doing all the files. The script runs with no issues but when I check the folder with all the .xml it seems to not check some files but others are done correctly. Not sure why is that occurring. In your where clause I see you have -CaseSensitive and -SimpleMatch ...would that be a factor?

Comment: I'm not a mind reader. Compare the xml files and see what's different.